# Google Sheets webscript: How to set a response code

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I've seen many links of how to GET a response code, but is there a way, within the webscript of the Google Sheet, to SET a response code if a condition fails? e.g.

```
if(webscriptSharedToken != AUTH_TOKEN) {
    return setStatusCode(401); 
}
```

The idea would be to use this returned error code to prevent certain functions within the application I'm creating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making a request to a Google API, that is you call a server side method - you will obtain a HTTP Response coming from the server side - you cannot manipulate this response on the client side.

Comment: Would there be any way to return something similar? A string or something.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do, which language are you using and to where do you want to return a response? To the browser window?

Comment: I am creating a Flutter app (therefore Dart language), and using the Google Sheet webscript to read/write data to/from the Google sheet. I want to return SOMETHING (string/response/true/false) back to the Flutter app in order to allow or deny certain app functions.

Comment: I assume you are calling a function within which data is read / written. You can implement a return value into your function. You can assign the response code you obtain from your request to a variable and use it as your return value.